# digest of a pandas Index

Tags: python, pandas, digest

I would like to **efficiently** compute a digest of a Pandas DataFrame that uniquely and reproducibly identifies its content (for versioning purposes).  Assume for now that I don't worry about endianness, dtypes, types of the index nor columns.  Also assume that both index and columns are already sorted monotonic_increasing.

Things go reasonably well with the values (again, for simplification, assume `np.float64`).  But I am having trouble with the index (and columns) and don't get a consistent digest.  Of course I can do things such as converting the index into String and then utf-8 bytes, but that is slow.

Here is a simplified example:

```
import hashlib
def pd_val_sha1(df):
    x = df.values
    if not x.flags.c_contiguous:
        x = x.copy(order='C')
    return hashlib.sha1(x).hexdigest()
```

Test:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

str = """s,e,id,x,y,z
2012-01-01,2013-01-01,b,NaN,2,3
2015-10-27,2015-11-03,a,0.04,12.7,NaN
2015-11-15,2016-01-01,a,7.3,-1.2,8
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str), parse_dates=[0,1], index_col=[0,1,2]).sort_index()
df
```

Out:

```
                            x     y    z
s          e          id                 
2012-01-01 2013-01-01 b    NaN   2.0  3.0
2015-10-27 2015-11-03 a   0.04  12.7  NaN
2015-11-15 2016-01-01 a   7.30  -1.2  8.0
```

SHA-1 of the values:

```
pd_val_sha1(df)
>>> 'a7f0335988a967606bd030864e0e30ce03f32ec9'

pd_val_sha1(df.head())
>>> 'a7f0335988a967606bd030864e0e30ce03f32ec9'

pd_val_sha1(pd.concat([df.ix[0:2], df.ix[2:3]]))
>>> 'a7f0335988a967606bd030864e0e30ce03f32ec9'
```

So far, so good.  But when it comes to the index:

```
pd_val_sha1(df.index)
>>> inconsistent value (re-run the example from read_csv and we'll get
... a different result).
```

I tried various other things, e.g. using `index.data` or `index.to_native_types()` or `np.array(index.tolist())` instead of `index.values`, but I still get inconsistent results, as I suppose the underlying data can vary.

One thing that seems to be working so far is `hashlib.sha1(np.array(df.index.format())).hexdigest()`.  But it is slow, e.g. 2min 34s for a (5000000,12) dataframe, whereas the content itself is fingerprinted in 900ms.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the solution is right under our nose...

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

%%time
joblib.hash(df, hash_name='sha1')
>>> consistent value that depends on values and axes
Wall time: 1.66 s  (for the (5000000,12) DataFrame mentioned above)
```